# how can I use switch case in less code using java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

here is the question:

Enter any character from keyboard, using switch case find whether charcater type:

**alphabet**, **digit**, **arithmetic operator** or **relation operator** or any **special character**?

find if it is alphabet it is uppercase or lower case

Comment: Yes Sir!! What else can I do for you? :P

Comment: Thanks, but still having difficulty of finding a solution for the switch,,,

Comment: what difficulty? can you post code

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Post your current code and show where you're stuck.  Currently, it just looks like you're asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: its not an assignment, I just want to see my ability to do this application, I am not asking for a code, I am asking for the idea on how the switch case could take those alphabet, digit, arithmetic operator or relation operator or any special character in shrieked code...

Answer (score 1):

Look at the java java.lang.Character class.  There are methods isLetter(), isDigit(), isWhitespace(), etc.  static methods which should help coalesce your code greatly.

Comment: yes I sure know the library, the problem is the main logic of the switch case

Comment: @RafedAlDoohan You can loop over the string using String's `charAt` method, something like: switch(yourString.charAt(index)). Then on each char you can use the methods that Albert described.